# What happens to "Reversed Votes" from the Perpetrator's Perspective?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, voting-correction

So, let's say "User-A" goes on a rage-fest against "User-B" and downvotes 10 of the latter's answers in a spell of a few minutes. The *immediate* consequence of this is that User-A will lose 10 reputation points, and User-B will lose 20 reputation points.

Subsequently, over the course of the next 24 hours or so, our old friend "Community ♦" (or one of its bots) will spot this action and the votes will be corrected ('reversed') **as far as User-B is concerned** (and User-B will get the +20 green reputation-change notification pop-up).

However, what is not clear to me is what happens to User-A (the perpetrator) when the votes get reversed:

1. Do they get the 10 reputation back?
2. Can they subsequently re-cast the down-votes (on the same posts)?
3. Are they notified in any way that what they've done is bad?

A slightly different case would be when the serial voting was applied to *questions* - in which case the perpetrator would not lose any reputation, so point #1 is then not relevant (but #2 and #3 still are).

Comment: 1. yes 2. yes 3. no

Comment: @samcarter So, as #2 is a "yes" they can just go repeat their actions but more discreetly (to prevent the system spotting it as serial voting) - seems odd, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, it is odd and not well thought through, like so many others things on stackoverflow

Comment: If we'd made #2 a no, that would save us nothing, as the perp could easily find 10 other answers to downvote, assuming it's directed to an active user.

Comment: Even if the question is different, the answer covers the question completely, I think.

Comment: Not notice for the voters is ok. I don't think we should try to educate people involved in serial voting about how bad it is. I believe they already know that. I can't impersonate the serial voters mind, but i do believe that a confrontational notice may be a bad idea.

Comment: @DragandDrop It could also be an issue where they did not realize they were serial voting on a user's questions as they could be just hitting a lot of answers on a tag and not paying attention to who wrote it.